# Get the name of the group in which a layer is stored using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I made a script that export the SLD stile from the layers in my QGIS project, but... I'm attempting to get the name of the group in which the layer is stored, to use it as a variable for creating a folder to store the sld. How can I do this?

```py
import processing
self=qgis.utils
layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()

for layer in layers:
    name = layer.name()
    pathsld = 'C:/Style/SLD/'+str(name)+'.sld'  
    layer.saveSldStyle(pathsld)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current group of the layer by making each layer selected in turn.

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
layer_tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()
for layer in layers:
    layer_tree_view.setCurrentLayer(layer)
    print(layer_tree_view.currentGroupNode().name())
```